# Getting MissingVotesFromCoordinator and disputes every block

Tags: networking

I am running relay chain based on polkadot-v0.9.40 and I have a connected parachain. I am getting the following error for a couple of days now on the Validator nodes.

```
2023-12-24 11:51:12 New dispute initiated for candidate. candidate_hash=0x81ba3f030282452844806ce5e7c7890d15b8a53131837aa3bc741640e66a182e session=13462 traceID=172437456702207600103813242361215420685
2023-12-24 11:51:12 Dispute on candidate concluded with 'valid' result candidate_hash=0x81ba3f030282452844806ce5e7c7890d15b8a53131837aa3bc741640e66a182e session=13462 traceID=172437456702207600103813242361215420685
2023-12-24 11:51:12 error=Sender(MissingVotesFromCoordinator) ctx="on FromOrchestra"
2023-12-24 11:51:12 � Imported #5357788 (0x2e99�16ca)
2023-12-24 11:51:12 error=Sender(MissingVotesFromCoordinator) ctx="on FromOrchestra"
2023-12-24 11:51:12 � Idle (10 peers), best: #5357788 (0x1ae1�3371), finalized #5357785 (0xfd9e�d5de), � 7.3kiB/s � 8.1kiB/s
2023-12-24 11:51:17 � Idle (10 peers), best: #5357788 (0x1ae1�3371), finalized #5357786 (0x1331�9845), � 8.0kiB/s � 6.8kiB/s
2023-12-24 11:51:18 Recent disputes are excessive (1308 > 1000), reduce to active ones, and selected
```

The relay chain and parachain seems to run normal (transactions, production of blocks, finality, etc), but it seems that it rejects new connections

```
2023-12-24 12:02:16 Accepting new connection 7/1000
2023-12-24 12:02:16 Rejected connection: Transport(header Upgrade not found)
```